# Debezium Embedded Database Connection Management/Pooling

Tags: cdc, debezium

I am using Debezium embedded and seems to be working nicely for me in single application development environment.  However I have concerns about having this in a multi node environment where mutliple instances of the application will try to open connections to same DB to monitor the log.  Would there need to be a connection pooling implementation??  I can't find info on this in the documentation.

Comment: May I ask why you're using embedded mode? Streaming to Kafka (via the regular Kafka Connect deployment style) allows for multiple consumers of change events (from Kafka topics) with a single reader of the change log. Also, if your app nodes were part of the same consumer group, only one of them would process each event. Would be interesting to learn more about your specific use case to give more solid advice.

Comment: Kafka is not an option for us(company decision).We're in a position where we need a pub/sub solution where we want to keep DB table in sync with an in memory database,again company decision. We had some old rabbit instance which I'm told we're also no longer supporting so pretty limited here.Debezium embedded seems to suit our needs & we can implement it without disrupting architecture.My Only concern here having multiple applications connecting back to read DB log tables be an issue.We have 12 instances in production which would be pointed to same DB. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

While not an expert at Debezium, I do manage the IBM Data Replication portfolio, so this answer is with that in mind.

Definitions:

Change data feed = inserts, updates, deletes made to one of more tables captured via recovery/transaction/undo log

Typically, if you have multiple consumer of a change data event feed, the appropriate design choice would be to land that feed in a queue once, and then have multiple readers on that queue, avoiding the need to have multiple log readers.

The queue could then be read by multiple consumers.  Examples of queues are "staging audit tables", ie, tables that contain the change feed.   You would need to kull the audit tables periodically to keep them from growing to large.

Another popular choice is staging to Kafka.   Kafka is oriented to many readers with small number of writers.

Some mature products (like the IBM Data Replication portfolio) have features exactly designed to meet the use case of many consumers of the original change feed, ie, what is called "scrape cache" or "single scraper".   In this way, the replication tools can send the original change feed to many targets, including databases, Hadoop and Kafka with only a single log read on the source database.

Cheers!